# trouble in starting jboss server

Tags: jboss5.x

I'm trying to start jboss but the it's not getting started. It gives the following error

```
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/portal/jbossPayments/jboss-5.1.0.GA

  JAVA: /usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_19/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run_pmnts_ports_01.sh -server -Xms2650m -Xmx2650m -XX:+AggressiveHeap  -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=12 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsu
n.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8987,server=y,suspend=n

  CLASSPATH: /opt/portal/jbossPayments/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.jar::/opt/portal/jbossPayments/jboss-5.1.0.GA/config:/usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_19/lib/tools.jar

=========================================================================

FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: is there any other application running on same server ?

Comment: yes there are two more other applications running

Comment: One possible reason may be that PortNumber of two applications is same, can u plz check that...

Comment: Thank u..... I got it fixed and it started